# How to filter two attributes in SQLalchemy

Tags: python, flask, filter, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to know if I can create only one query using Flask SQLalchemy that will provide me all rows from one table that has two attributes Id and name but like this:
If I don't define attributes it returns me all rows of table, if I define Id it returns the row with that Id, if I define name it returns rows with that name and if I define both it returns row with that attributes.

It should look like something like this:

```
Table.query.filter ( _or(Table.id==id, Table.name==name ).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

To do exactly what you want, notably fetching everything when a filter field is `None`, one solution could be to create a function for that:

```
def search(Table, **kwargs):
    if not kwargs:
        return db.query(Table).all()
    filters = {k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if v is not None}
    return db.query(Table).filter_by(**filters).all()
```

<sup>Assuming `db` is your SqlAlchemy session object</sup>

Then you can use it like this:

```
search(YourModel) # fetch everything
search(YourModel, name=None) # fetch everything
search(YourModel, name='Hello') # fetch all YourModel with name='Hello'
search(YourModel, name='Hello', id=123) # fetch all YourModel with name='Hello' and id=123
```